# Jquery change th value

Tags: jquery

How can I change the th value in JQuery with my id table ? I want to get the value of my thead th and change it when I click on a button but I don't know how to get the th attribute.

```
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <table id="table1" class="table">
            <thead>
              <th class="text-center">My header</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Category<input type="checkbox"/></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Choose</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: `$('#tableid').find('thead')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I change the th value in JQuery with my id table

th elements do not have value associated to them.if you mean content of it then you can use `.text()` or `.html()` along with th selector:

```
$('#tableid tg').text();  // My header
```

> I want to get the value of my thead th and change it when I click

You can use `.text()` or `.html()` with new content as argument to set new content

```
 $('#tableid tg').text('New Header');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$("#table1 thead th").text("Different header text");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = $('th', '#table1').html(); //"My header"
$('th', '#table1').html('new value'); //sets "new value"
```